# PageKit / Symfony Throwing "Session Data File Not Created By UID" Error Windows 10

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pagekit

I have php installed on Windows 10 through the linux sublayer using Ubuntu 18.04.

Then I create a windows symlink for my projects to the /var/www/ folder so that I can access it via

`localhost/project-folder-name`

This has always worked fine until I tried to install PageKit to a project folder. Now for some reason I am getting the following error

```
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid
```

I am assuming this is some sort of ownership issue due to how I have PHP installed, but I am not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?